# SQL iteration though several levels of parent/child hierarchy

Tags: sql, recursion, hierarchical-data

Background: I have 3 MSSQLServer tables: product, category, product_category_mapping.  there are up to 5 levels of categories above the product and this data is held in the mapping table.
What I want to do is iterate though the products and for every product category level, create a new mapping for that product against the current level.

I started with this query, and thought I could develop it by putting cursors at each category stage, where I would perform the insert. Once I started found it hard to get my head around, and now I'm wondering if this is even the best way to go about it - can someone show me a better way of doing this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductId,p.name
FROM Nop_Product p 
INNER JOIN Nop_Product_Category_Mapping cm ON p.ProductId = cm.ProductID
INNER JOIN Nop_Category c  ON cm.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
WHERE c.CategoryID in (
     --next level
    SELECT DISTINCT Nop_Category.CategoryID
     FROM Nop_Product_Category_Mapping
    INNER JOIN Nop_Category  ON Nop_Product_Category_Mapping.CategoryID = Nop_Category.CategoryID
    WHERE Nop_Category.ParentCategoryID in (
    -- next level
        SELECT DISTINCT Nop_Category.CategoryID
         FROM Nop_Product_Category_Mapping
        INNER JOIN Nop_Category  ON Nop_Product_Category_Mapping.CategoryID = Nop_Category.CategoryID
        WHERE Nop_Category.ParentCategoryID in (
        -- next level
            SELECT DISTINCT Nop_Category.CategoryID
             FROM Nop_Product_Category_Mapping
            INNER JOIN Nop_Category  ON Nop_Product_Category_Mapping.CategoryID = Nop_Category.CategoryID
            WHERE Nop_Category.ParentCategoryID in (
                -- next level
                SELECT DISTINCT Nop_Category.CategoryID
                 FROM Nop_Product_Category_Mapping
                INNER JOIN Nop_Category  ON Nop_Product_Category_Mapping.CategoryID = Nop_Category.CategoryID
                WHERE Nop_Category.ParentCategoryID in (
                --top level categories
                    SELECT Nop_Category.CategoryID
                    FROM Nop_Product_Category_Mapping 
                    INNER JOIN Nop_Category  ON Nop_Product_Category_Mapping.CategoryID = Nop_Category.CategoryID
                    WHERE Nop_Category.ParentCategoryID = 0)))))
```

Comment: What RDBMS? MSSQLServer?

Comment: In addition to the comment from @Pablo - are you to post some sample DDL and data?

Comment: MySQL (nor SQLite) doesn't have hierarchical support, but [provides this info to help](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html).  SQL Server didn't get hierarchical support until 2005; Oracle's had hierarchical support since v2.  Dunno about others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's Microsoft SQL Server, you can try using [CTE (Common Table Expressions) for recursive queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

If it's PostgreSQL you have [support for recursive queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html) also.

[Here's](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1221236349834) how to do it in Oracle.

Comment: OK. Take a look at CTE then. Good Luck!